# How to plot interaction effects of a mixed model in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression, mixed-models

I would like to get predictions for the interaction effect a model (e.g. using `sjPlot::plot_model` or `ggeffects` package and then feed them to ggplot2 to visualize the interaction in ggplot2. Could someone please help with the code to do that? My question is different than other on stack because it inovles getting predictions using standard packages first, and then plotting them.

My current model:

```
model <- glmmTMB(total_count ~ mean_temp*lwd_duration + (1|year), family = nbinom1, data=df)

summary(model)

Family: nbinom1  ( log )
Formula:          total_count ~ mean_temp * lwd_duration + (1 | year)
Data: df

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   260.6    270.7   -124.3    248.6       34 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 year   (Intercept) 3.683e-09 6.069e-05
Number of obs: 40, groups:  year, 4

Dispersion parameter for nbinom1 family ():  178 

Conditional model:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)             9.609769   3.276724   2.933  0.00336 **
mean_temp              -0.341435   0.177426  -1.924  0.05431 . 
lwd_duration           -0.105528   0.039145  -2.696  0.00702 **
mean_temp:lwd_duration  0.005819   0.002078   2.801  0.00510 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Reproducible example:

```
df <- structure(list(year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                        4L), levels = c("2017", "2016", "2015", "2014"), class = "factor"), 
                     mean_temp = c(10.31, 10.31, 11.35, 11.35, 14.05, 14.05, 15.96, 
                                   15.96, 16.73, 16.73, 20.92, 20.92, 21.89, 21.89, 21.48, 21.48, 
                                   25.82, 25.82, 21.06, 21.06, 16.3, 16.3, 20.16, 20.16, 19.85, 
                                   19.85, 25.45, 25.45, 24.32, 24.32, 20.59, 20.78, 20.78, 20.78, 
                                   22.23, 22.23, 22.23, 19.71, 19.71, 19.71), lwd_duration = c(116.53, 
                                                                                               116.53, 146.18, 146.18, 184.48, 184.48, 67.3, 67.3, 70.08, 
                                                                                               70.08, 71.43, 71.43, 68.58, 68.58, 91.6, 91.6, 72.07, 72.07, 
                                                                                               59.57, 59.57, 13.02, 13.02, 75.33, 75.33, 60.07, 60.07, 98.08, 
                                                                                               98.08, 71.78, 71.78, 40.25, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 32.47, 32.47, 
                                                                                               32.47, 61.73, 61.73, 61.73), total_count = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                            0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                            0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 18L, 362L, 135L, 684L, 34L, 123L, 21L, 
                                                                                                                                            6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 13L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                       year = structure(1:4, levels = c("2017", "2016", "2015", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "2014"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:10, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           11:20, 21:30, 31:40), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "tbl", "data. Frame")))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typical way to do this from scratch would be to create a data frame of all the combinations of your predictors, then run `predict` on it:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
library(ggplot2)

model <- glmmTMB(total_count ~ mean_temp*lwd_duration + (1|year),
                 family = nbinom1, data = df)
model

pred_df <- expand.grid(mean_temp = seq(10, 25, len = 100),
                       lwd_duration = seq(10, 200, 0.1),
                       year = factor(2017, 2017:2014))

pred_df$total_count <- predict(model, newdata = pred_df, type = "response")
```

There are various ways to plot the result, but choosing one variable for the color scale and one for the x axis gives an aesthetically pleasing and fairly intuitive output. You could show temperature on the x axis:

```r
ggplot(pred_df, aes(mean_temp, total_count, color = lwd_duration,
                    group = lwd_duration)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = range(df$total_count), xlim = range(df$mean_temp)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 22)
```

[image]

Or use temperature for color:

```r
ggplot(pred_df, aes(lwd_duration, total_count, color = mean_temp,
                    group = mean_temp)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "RdBu") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = range(df$total_count), xlim = range(df$lwd_duration)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 22)
```

[image]

Although the plots look good, I suspect they are a bit over-fit if you plot the actual data alongside them.

---

If you want to use `ggpredict`, you could do something like:

```r
ggpredict(model, terms = c("mean_temp[10:27]", "lwd_duration[10:200]"),
          type = "random") %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename(mean_temp = x, lwd_duration = group, total_count = predicted) %>%
  mutate(lwd_duration = as.numeric(as.character(lwd_duration))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mean_temp, total_count, color = lwd_duration, 
             group = lwd_duration)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = df, shape = 21, aes(fill = lwd_duration), color = "black",
             size = 2.5) +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", guide = "none") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = range(df$total_count), xlim = range(df$mean_temp)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log1p") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 22)
```

[image]

Note that you can edit the range and density of the terms in the square brackets after the term name (see Details in the help file). You might only be able to use a few levels of each predictor, and you can only plot a maximum of three variables - the other variables will be held steady.

Comment: @Ahsk I'm not sure what you mean about "feeding" results to ggplot. Both the packages you mention create ggplot objects already. If you have a plot you like from one of these packages you can usually extract the data from it quite easily to pass to a new plot. Perhaps you could edit uour question to include an example of a plot from which you wish to extract data?

Comment: You mean something like `ggeffect(model, c("mean_temp", "lwd_duration")) %>% plot()`? Or `ggeffect(model, c("mean_temp", "lwd_duration")) %>% as.data.frame()`?

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me. This is the complete code, but I can't seem to get it to work: `dfL <- pivot_longer(df, -c(year, total_count), names_to = "var"); pred <- map_dfr(ggpredict(model), as.data.frame) |> rename(value = "x", total_count = "predicted", var = "group"); ggplot(dfL, aes(value, total_count, colour = lwd_duration)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~var, scale = "free_x") + scale_y_continuous(trans = "log1p") + geom_line(data = pred, colour = "black") + geom_ribbon(data = pred, colour = NA, fill = "black", alpha = 0.1, aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)`

Comment: @Ahsk change `color = lwd_duration` to `color = var`

Comment: @Ahsk changing `lwd_duration` to `var` using your code and sample data produced a faceted plot with one panel for each of the two variables. It's a decent plot, but it doesn't show interactions.

Comment: @Ahsk I think I understand. See my update. You will still run into problems with memory and crashing unless you limit the number of levels you use in each variable.

Comment: @Ahsk yes, that's right. the fit doesn't look great, but remember that we can't see the random effects on this plot , which might make a big different